# Как подключить вторую БД к проекту?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть один очень крупный проект (около 100 таблиц) на Rails 5.1.2. И он переписывается.

Переписывается с нуля, проектируется новая архитектура БД, новые модели, связи и прочее. Но в итоге это все тот же самый проект, данные в новой версии по сути будут отображаться те же.

По ходу реализации новых разделов в проекте нужно будет заполнять соответствующие (разделу) таблицы.

Я взял все модели из старого проекта и поместил их в новый в каталог `models/old`. И для начала в `application_record.rb` и `post.rb`, в имена классов добавил `Old::`.

Еще в `database.yml` я добавил новые данные (от второй БД) и в `application_record.rb` добавил строку `establish_connection 'development_old'`.

В итоге получилось это:

```
class Old::ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection 'development_old'
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

И одна тестовая модель:

```
class Old::Post < Old::ApplicationRecord
    # ...
end
```

Ну и `database.yml` для полной картины:

```
development_old:
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    pool: 10
    host: 11.22.33.44
    port: 5432
    database: 111
    username: 222
    password: 333
```

В итоге в консоле прописываю `rails c -e development`, далее: `Old::Post.all` и получаю:

```
ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified: database configuration does not specify adapter
    from app/models/old/application_record.rb:2:in `<class:ApplicationRecord>'
    from app/models/old/application_record.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from app/models/old/post.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from (irb):1
```

Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Плохо:

```
establish_connection 'development_old'
```

Хорошо:

```
establish_connection :development_old
```